# como colocar efeito sonoro ao clicar o botão

Tags: android

Fiz o botão

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="178dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:onClick="clickMyamarela"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/botao_amarelo"
    android:background="@drawable/baamarela"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
```

mas não sei muita coisa ainda, e queria colocar um som, o toque já está na pasta raw.

Como colocar efeito sonoro ao clicar o botão?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar assim:

**Activity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SoundEffectsInAndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button button;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // init Effects class
        Effects.getInstance().init(this);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Effects.getInstance().playSound(Effects.SOUND_1);
    }
}
```

**Classe Effects**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Effects {

    private static final String TAG = Effects.class.toString();

    private static final Effects INSTANCE = new Effects();

    // Sound ID can't be 0 (zero)
    public static final int SOUND_1 = 1;

    private Effects() {

    }

    public static Effects getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;
    int priority = 1;
    int no_loop = 0;
    private int volume;
    float normal_playback_rate = 1f;

    private Context context;

    public void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundPoolMap.put(SOUND_1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound_1, 1));
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
    }

    public void playSound(int soundId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!! playSound_1 !!!!!!!!!!");
        soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Now you can hear sound effect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```